# Is this the right way of logging in Flask?

Tags: python, logging, flask

I have written a Flask App as follows:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from mongo import Mongo
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("config.ProductionConfig")


# routes to a particular change and patch number
@app.route("/<project>/")
def home(project):

    app.logger.info('testing info log')
    Mongo_obj = Mongo(ip=app.config["DB_HOST"], port=app.config["DB_PORT"],
                      username=app.config["DB_USERNAME"],

.....................
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = '5000')
```

Now, the problem I face is, when I look at the logs of the Flask application, all I see is the following:

```
* Serving Flask app "service" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
172.16.40.189 - - [01/Oct/2019 14:44:29] "GET /abc HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.11.231 - - [01/Oct/2019 14:44:29] "GET /abc HTTP/1.1" 200 -
............
```

Is there something specific that needs to be done in order to see the log message? Do I need to run the Flask App in debug mode?

Comment: Did you not try to run Flask in debug first? Is there a reason you want to log "in Flask". I'd say the correct way is to log from a logger in your app, that is associated with the class or file you are calling the logger from. There you can set your own format and variables and you know where the logging is happening.

Comment: I would say there is nothing wrong with using the logging module. I do it all the time. What matters is have someone or something to look at them.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues, is there something wrong I am doing in logging? Why do I not see the log message?

Comment: Have you checked the [flask documentation chapter](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/logging/) on logging?

Comment: @JohnDoe not sure about the flask  thing, as for the standard lib logging module your missing any sort of [configuration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I set log levels in our app. I use the `create_app` function to create a flask app with error handling logging & other necessary configurations. Here is the snippet:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    # Test Log levels
    app.logger.debug("debug log info")
    app.logger.info("Info log information")
    app.logger.warning("Warning log info")
    app.logger.error("Error log info")
    app.logger.critical("Critical log info")
    return app

app = create_app()
```

Output show only error and lower logs are visible for now

```
 * Restarting with stat
[2022-12-12 17:38:39,375] ERROR in __init__: Error log info
[2022-12-12 17:38:39,375] CRITICAL in __init__: Critical log info
```

Answer (score 0):

If not in debug mode the default log level is `WARNING`. That's why you don't see your logs. If you'd like your logs to contain `INFO` level ones you must set it within the logger, eg:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```